# I'm not able to pass the UID that I get from pushing data to my firebase db, to other javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app that requires me to keep track of the current UID that I get once a user pushes data to firebase. I do this by using the .push method and a unique key is generated and placed in my db for the records associated to that. This is what I'm considering my UID. I created a global variable in my javascript file, set the global var to the UID that is being generated and am simply trying to console.log(UID) in a seperate javascript file where I need access to the current UID. However, every time I try to log in the other js file, I get UID = undefined. Pretty sure I called my files properly in the html script tags and have tried putting them both in the head tags and in the body but still getting errors..

```js
//Form.js file where I get the UID
var UID; //global var
$(document).ready(function(){
  var postData = function(){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    ...//create json object testData
    ...//create json object testData
    firebaseRef.push(testData).then((snap) =>     {
      UID = snap.key; //the unique key is my UID
      console.log("this is the UID", UID) //logs
    });
  };
    
//--------------------------
//Feed.js File
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("uid =", UID); //returns uid = undefined
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 ...
 </head>

 <body>
   <script src="javascripts/form.js"></script>
   <script src="javascripts/feed.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate your testdata and please tell what is it? for me it's console logged. when did  firebaseRef.push("hi").then((snap) =>     {
    UID = snap.key; //the unique key is my UID
    console.log("this is the UID", UID) //logs
  }); it's printed

Comment: test data is just a json object that I create and push to my database. I don't think its really effecting this issue I'm having. I create this test data object and push to firebase. When I do this, I generate a unique ID that this object cooresponds to and store it in a global called UID. Just not being able to reference this global in my other javascript file

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the `push({data})` is equal to `push().set({data})`. Set() is async and returns a Promise. Because it is async you cannot know if the UID is already there when you make the console log. in this case, because the async function has not resolved, UID is not set at the time of the console.log and you get undefined.

One Solution: 
Im just gonna name ur global getUID 
`var = getUID; 
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    ...//create json object testData
  getUID = firebaseRef.push(testData);
})`

This will make UID a Promise. Then in feed.js you put: 
`getUID.then((snap) => {console.log("uid =", snap.key) + rest of your code that uses uid})`

You can also know the key beforehand by just calling `UID = firebaseRef.push()` (push() itself is synchronous) and then call firebaseRef.set(data). But mind that in this case you cannot be certain that the data was succesfully uploaded to firebase.

More about promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

It works with a mock promise, after 3 secs you get the console log:

```js
var getUID; 

$(document).ready(function(){
 getUID = new Promise (function (resolve){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     resolve("Hello world");
   }, 3000);
  });
})

$(document).ready(function(){
 getUID.then(function(value) {console.log(value)})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this in code but still getting that my global UID is undefined and cannot read property of 'then' on undefined. :(

Comment: yea, I create the mock promise and set to getUID in my **form.js**

Then in my **feed.js**, I call getUID.then(function(value) {
  console.log("UID in feed.js",value);
 });

but I get an error saying "cannot read property then of undefined"

Comment: yea if both js file are in different html files it doesn't work, but thats not what the example  code in your question said :P but good to see u solved it with localstorage ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
var UID;
$(document).ready(function(){
    UID= firebaseRef.push().key;
    firebaseRef.child(UID).set(testData);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log(UID) //put a debugger in the console and check which document.ready called first.
});
```

Your problem occurs in the document.ready function because you have two of them at once, firebase.set is async call as so as soon  you call them it doesn't wait for the "then" method to execute, it switches to the other statement (i.e your another document.ready and prints the console.log(UID), then when the set is done it switches back to the "then" method and then assigns the key to the UID.

Comment: I put a debugger in the console for both .js files and it looks like the first form.js executes but then it re executes form.js at which point UID has become undefined and then it executes my feed.js....how do I prevent this?

Comment: which one is getting executed first is your form.js or feed.js?

Comment: form.js gets executed first, then once again after I try navigating to feed.html and then finally feed.js gets executed

Comment: when the form.js gets executed, put a debugger in var UID and check then when the push is executed is then check the "UID = snap.key" then when the feed.js gets executed again check var UID, if it's gets value then it's ok, if not then var UID is also getting refreshed when you're navigating to feed.html.

Comment: yea it doesn't persist. it doesn't get the value so maybe that global var is being refreshed when I navigate to feed.html using window.location.href = "./feed"

Comment: Ofcourse it is refreshed, when you go to a new page all JS is run again from 0...

Comment: You would have to use localStorage or sessionStorage and save the UID there, or make your page an SPA (Single Page App).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Used Local Storage to pass the value across different .js files